# What does the term "Kingdom Come" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

I have been listening to lot of songs and I have come over this term, "Kingdom Come", several times. I cannot quite place the meaning of it. Internet search only shows that it is a part of text of the Holy Bible.

Imagine dragons "demons" is one of them with lyrics as below:

> No matter what we breed
>   We still are made of greed
>   This is my kingdom come
>   This is my kingdom come

Please clarify the meaning.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kingdom+come it roughly means afterlife.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people may use the phrase "Kingdom come" to refer to *heaven* or *forever*

> I will be working here until Kingdom come

however there is an alternative definition which refers to [the next world](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/kingdom%20come).  Both definitions provided in the link are badly referring to the Holy Bible and the Lord's Prayer.  If the many Internet websites out there are correct on the origin, it is strange when you look at the origin.

The origin is indicated on these websites as being from the Lord's Prayer from the line

> Your Kingdom come (English Standard Version)

or

> Thy Kingdom come (King James' Version)

which is asking for [the reign of God be fully established](https://www.reference.com/world-view/biblical-meaning-phrase-thy-kingdom-come-8e7d059b30ad27cc)

Now for your reference to *Kingdom come*, without knowing what songs you are referring to, you could be referring to a hip hop slang where *Kingdom come* is meaning [new home](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kingdom+come)

> Yo Jay's Kingdom come is da illest!

**------ Edit after OP edit------**

Looking at the [full lyrics](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tlwopcmipeoqmhp4nnvfafyj4ey?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) of the Imagine Dragons song Demons, they are referring to hell (the opposite of heaven) - *Kingdom come* being *next world* - as they are talking about idol worshipping and greed.